# If else ladder optimisation

Tags: if-statement

```
 if (value >= 2) {
    return 1
} else if (value >= 1) {
    return 0.9;
} else if (value >= 0.8) {
    return 0.7
} else if (value >= 0.5) {
    return 0.5;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

How to solve this if-else ladder. If i use switch cyclometric complexity increases and also also values feels like true.

Comment: It's looking good already, you can't do much better.

Comment: It's absolutely horrible - never do that

Comment: do note that in your *specific* example, pls read about "breakaway code below", you can literally just "delete all the elses" !!!  since it *is* breakaway code!

Comment: What do you mean by "optimisation" by the way? What don't you like in this code? You want it more readable? More maintainable? More performant? It can't be much more performant than that. Readability is slightly subjective, you could use constants instead of magic numbers if you wish. You could also "drop the elses" if you find it more elegant that way, as @Fattie suggested. I personally find it acceptable as is :)

Comment: it's a good point that "optimization" in the sense of "runs fast" is absolutely not what the OP meant, good one.  The OP just means "better" engineering - clearer, more maintainable, whatever is trendy these years in software engineering  :O

Comment: But... How do you know what the OP meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases the solution is **breakaway** code.  Not everyone likes it - I do like it.

It just means you handle situations "from the top" and **end situations with a return**

pseudocode in any language...

(Everything should be in a function anyway...)

```
HandleTemperature(float t)
{
 if (t > 90)
  {
  RunEmergencyCooling();
  return;
  }
 if (round.t == 63)
  {
  DealWithgMagicValue();
  return;
  }

 if (round.t > 40)
  {
  Debug.("normal temps! no worries!);
  return;
  }

 // if you get to here, temp is very lopw
 RunEmergencyHeating();
}
```

(In many languages there's a "finally" or "always do" concept, which can work well w/. breakaway dcode.)

## Your example ...

Step 1, put in in a function as it should be anyway, Step 2 use "breakaway chunks".

```
float HandleValue(float v)
{
 
 if (2.0 <= v) {
    return 1
 }

 if (0.7 < v && v < 2.0) {
    return 0.9;
 }

 if (0.13 <= v && v <= 0.7) {
    return 17.6;
 }
 
 log didn't find a bracket in HandleValue
 return default value
}
```

Every bracket is totally explicit. You can easily build testing code from there, too.

## Those annoying long blocks before errors ...

Breakaway is particularly clean-looking in error cases...

```
Something()
{
if comms.text != 17.2
 {
 .. 100s of lines of code here ..
 .. they are all indented ..
 }
else
 {
 an error!
 }
}
```

Some (but not all) believe this is better:

```
Something()
{
if comms.text == 17.2
 {
 an error!
 return; .. note the "return" in breakaway code
 }

.. 100s of lines of code here ..
.. no need for indentation ..
}
```

"Breakaway code" may work for you in some cases; in any event you can be aware of the approach.