# Speedup an if-else ladder C++

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement, optimization, execution-time

I have a piece of code that demands execution speed over anything else. By using the `high_resolution_clock()` from `std::chrono` I found out that this switch() into if-else() ladder is taking over 70% of my execution time. Is there any way to speed this up?

I'm using `gcc` with `-O3` optimization during compiling.

I looked into a similar question: [If else ladder optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65328242/if-else-ladder-optimisation) but I can't use a return statement as it would exit the outer loop which I can't.

```
switch(RPL_OPTION) {
            case 0:
                for(int k = 0; k < WINDOW_SIZE; k++) {
                    if(ans[k] >= upper_th) {
                        //Increasing flag counter
                        flag_count++;
                        //Adding the filtered value to the output vector
                        filtered_output.push_back(ans[k]);
                        flag_output.push_back(1);

                    } else if(ans[k] < lower_th) {
                        //Increasing flag counter
                        flag_count++;
                        //Adding the filtered value to the output vector
                        filtered_output.push_back(ans[k]);
                        flag_output.push_back(1);

                    } else {
                        //Adding the filtered value to the output vector
                        filtered_output.push_back(ans[k]);
                        flag_output.push_back(0);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                for(int k = 0; k < WINDOW_SIZE; k++) {
                    if(ans[k] >= upper_th) {
                        //Increasing flag counter
                        flag_count++;
                        //Adding the filtered value to the output vector
                        filtered_output.push_back(RPL_CONST);
                        flag_output.push_back(1);

                    } else if(ans[k] < lower_th) {
                        //Increasing flag counter
                        flag_count++;
                        //Adding the filtered value to the output vector
                        filtered_output.push_back(RPL_CONST);
                        flag_output.push_back(1);

                    } else {
                        //Adding the filtered value to the output vector
                        filtered_output.push_back(ans[k]);
                        flag_output.push_back(0);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                for(int k = 0; k < WINDOW_SIZE; k++) {
                    if(ans[k] >= upper_th) {
                        //Increasing flag counter
                        flag_count++;
                        //Adding the filtered value to the output vector
                        filtered_output.push_back(upper_th);
                        flag_output.push_back(1);

                    } else if(ans[k] < lower_th) {
                        //Increasing flag counter
                        flag_count++;
                        //Adding the filtered value to the output vector
                        filtered_output.push_back(lower_th);
                        flag_output.push_back(1);

                    } else {
                        //Adding the filtered value to the output vector
                        filtered_output.push_back(ans[k]);
                        flag_output.push_back(0);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                //Generating a gaussian noise distribution with 0 mean and 1 std deviation
                default_random_engine generator(time(0));
                normal_distribution<float> dist(0,1);

                for(int k = 0; k < WINDOW_SIZE; k++) {
                    if(ans[k] >= upper_th) {
                        //Increasing flag counter
                        flag_count++;
                        //Calling a random sample from the distribution and calculating a noise value
                        filtered_output.push_back(dist(generator)*sigma);
                        flag_output.push_back(1);
                        continue;

                    } else if(ans[k] < lower_th) {
                        //Increasing flag counter
                        flag_count++;
                        //Calling a random sample from the distribution and calculating a noise value
                        filtered_output.push_back(dist(generator)*sigma);
                        flag_output.push_back(1);
                        continue;

                    } else {
                        //Adding the filtered value to the output vector
                        filtered_output.push_back(ans[k]);
                        flag_output.push_back(0);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
```

Comment: How much does the measured time decrease if you hoist the construction of the default_random_engine and the nornal_distribution out of the function, ie so that it only happens once rather than on every call?

Comment: Have you try to profile the 'pushback()' function? The burden may be the `pushback()` function not `if else` statements.

Comment: Note that `push_back()` (into a `std::vector`, presumably) has an `if-else` inside to check size against capacity.

Comment: a [mre] would be helpful

Comment: Seeing as you're going to add `WINDOW_SIZE` elements to your outputs in every case, you can resize them beforehand and then just assign the elements.

Comment: Concerning _I can't use a return statement_: This is simple to achieve with a lambda which is immediately called, something like `[&] { if (cond1) return; if (cond2) return; }();`. (Please, note the round brackets at the end.) However, I don't believe that this will buy any performance impact - it just may make the code nicer, maybe...

Comment: I would reckon as well that most of the time is being spent in the `push_back`s rather than the conditionals.

Comment: Before blaming the tests, make sure where the time-consuming operation is. Do profile the code.

Comment: @molbdnilo: A `.resize` would default-initialize the elements first. Did you mean `.reserve` ?

Comment: @MSalters I really don't think so.

Comment: @MSalters Personally, I would try both and measure; those capacity checks aren't free, either. I would also compare to gathering the outputs in local arrays and add all of them to the vectors at once.

Comment: How common is the case `lower <= ans[k] < upper_th` with your real data?

Comment: `default_random_engine generator(time(0));` seems a very bad idea since the `time(0)` function does not change frequently so numbers generated from a code calling it consecutively in a short period of time will generate the same result... the result is the opposite of the purpose of using a random number generator.

Comment: @molbdnilo: the `capacity` check is perfectly predicted due to the `reserve` and practically free as a result.  Sure, it takes a bit of uop cache, but this doesn't look like a big loop anyway.

Comment: @MSalters It is predicted well but it also prevents vectorization and in my experience creates worse code

Comment: Didn't expect to be back to so many replies,

The measured time isn't affected by the random engine significantly, each case takes about the same time, and is constant throughout the complete execution

I will try a version with avoiding `push_back()` 

The `lower <= ans[k] < upper_th` case occurs about 1-2% of times, not very frequent. I tried to think of a way to restructure but couldn't. 

@Scheff'sCat I tried and it didn't have much impact

I am sorry if I missed someone but thanks for the responses, can't mention everyone in one comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few optimizations that come to mind:

1. `vector.push_back()` or `emplace_back()`, even with `reserve()`, are poison for performance because no compiler is able to vectorize the code. We can work with plain C pointers instead or just preallocate.
2. Generating the random engine and distribution in the last case may have significant cost if this code is called repeatedly. We can hoist this out of the code. Note that this will also avoid issues with the repeated initialization for which you use a low-resolution time function.
3. This may be unnecessary but rewriting the code a bit may allow more compiler optimizations, especially by turning things into conditional move-instructions and reducing the number of branches.

```
/* TODO: We have better ways of initializing generators but that is
 * unrelated to its performance
 * I'm lazy and turn this into a static variable. Better use a
 * different pattern (like up in the stack somewhere)
 * but you get the idea
 */
static default_random_engine generator(time(0));
static normal_distribution<float> dist(0,1);

std::size_t output_pos = filtered_output.size();
filtered_output.resize(output_pos + WINDOW_SIZE);
flag_output.resize(output_pos + WINDOW_SIZE);

switch(RPL_OPTION) {
case 0:
    for(int k = 0; k < WINDOW_SIZE; k++) {
        auto ansk = ans[k];
        int flag = (ansk >= upper_th) | (ansk < lower_th);
        flag_count += flag;
        filtered_output[output_pos + k] = ansk;
        flag_output[output_pos + k] = flag;
    }
    break;
case 1:
    for(int k = 0; k < WINDOW_SIZE; k++) {
        auto ansk = ans[k];
        int flag = (ansk >= upper_th) | (ansk < lower_th);
        flag_count += flag;
        // written carefully to help compiler turning this into a CMOV
        auto filtered = flag ? RPL_CONST : ansk;
        filtered_output[output_pos + k] = filtered;
        flag_output[output_pos + k] = flag;
    }
    break;
case 2:
    for(int k = 0; k < WINDOW_SIZE; k++) {
        auto ansk = ans[k];
        int flag = (ansk >= upper_th) | (ansk < lower_th);
        flag_count += flag;
        auto filtered = ansk < lower_th ? lower_th : ansk;
        filtered = ansk >= upper_th ? upper_th : filtered;
        filtered_output[output_pos + k] = filtered;
        flag_output[output_pos + k] = flag;
    }
    break;
case 3:
    for(int k = 0; k < WINDOW_SIZE; k++) {
        // optimized under the assumption that flag is usually 1
        auto ansk = ans[k];
        auto random = dist(generator) * sigma;
        int flag = (ansk >= upper_th) | (ansk < lower_th);
        auto filtered = flag ? random : ansk;
        filtered_output[output_pos + k] = filtered;
        flag_output[output_pos + k] = flag;
    }
    break;
}
```

### Analyzing compiler output

I checked the resulting code with Godbolt. Cases 0-2 do vectorize. However, a lot hinges on good alias detection. So this needs to be analyzed in the context of the full function containing this code. Particular pain points are

- Potential alias between `ans` and `filtered_output`. That is hard to avoid but I think compilers should be able to create code that check against this
- Potential alias between the thresholds + `RPL_CONST` and the `filtered_output`. When in doubt, copy the inputs into a local variable (which the compiler can prove to be alias free). Just marking them const may not be enough
- Potential alias between `flag_count` and `flag_output`, depending on the types. Again, better use a local variable for the count, then copy it to its output, if required

As for case 3, computing a random sample is expensive enough that my optimization may degrade performance if the inputs are usually within limits. That needs benchmarking. The longer I think about it, losing a few clock cycles on a mis-predict is probably much less time than computing a sample without using it.

### Removing redundant code

The resulting code is highly redundant. We could move the switch-case into the loop but that messes with the vectorization. Instead, we can use a template function pattern.

```
class Filter
{
    int WINDOW_SIZE;
    float upper_th, lower_th, sigma, RPL_CONST;
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::normal_distribution<float> dist;

    template<class FilterOp>
    int apply(std::vector<float>& filtered_output,
              std::vector<int>& flag_output,
              const std::vector<float>& ans, FilterOp filter)
    {
        // move stuff into local variables to help with alias detection
        const int WINDOW_SIZE = this->WINDOW_SIZE;
        const float upper_th = this->upper_th, lower_th = this->lower_th;
        const std::size_t output_pos = filtered_output.size() - WINDOW_SIZE;
        int flag_count = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < WINDOW_SIZE; k++) {
            auto ansk = ans[k];
            int flag = (ansk >= upper_th) | (ansk < lower_th);
            flag_count += flag;
            filtered_output[output_pos + k] = filter(ansk, flag);
            flag_output[output_pos + k] = flag;
        }
        return flag_count;
    }
public:
    int operator()(int RPL_OPTION,
              std::vector<float>& filtered_output,
              std::vector<int>& flag_output,
              const std::vector<float>& ans)
    {
        std::size_t output_pos = filtered_output.size();
        filtered_output.resize(output_pos + WINDOW_SIZE);
        flag_output.resize(output_pos + WINDOW_SIZE);
        switch(RPL_OPTION) {
        case 0:
            return apply(filtered_output, flag_output, ans,
                [](float ansk, int flag) noexcept -> float {
                    return ansk;
            });
        case 1:
            return apply(filtered_output, flag_output, ans,
                [RPL_CONST=this->RPL_CONST](float ansk, int flag) noexcept -> float {
                    return flag ? RPL_CONST : ansk;
            });
        case 2:
            return apply(filtered_output, flag_output, ans,
                [lower_th=this->lower_th, upper_th=this->upper_th](
                      float ansk, int flag) noexcept -> float {
                    auto filtered = ansk < lower_th ? lower_th : ansk;
                    return ansk >= upper_th ? upper_th : filtered;
            });
         case 3:
            return apply(filtered_output, flag_output, ans,
                [this](float ansk, int flag) noexcept -> float {
                    return flag ? dist(generator)*sigma : ansk;
            });
         default: return 0;
       }
    }
};
```

Comment: `auto ansk = ansk[k]` ? I understand the manual CSE, you're not entirely consistent though. It's missing from `case 0`.

Comment: Would `emplace_back()` be better?

Comment: @MSalters I think the case 0 is simple enough that it is unnecessary. But for consistency it might be better

Comment: @LouisGo No, the if-statement in both functions is the issue. Compilers are just not smart enough to understand that they can loop safely for ```min(capacity, loop_count)``` iterations without checking the condition

Comment: You can have more readable code by moving the loop outside the switch and keeping the common code (loads and stores from/into arrays) in all cases outside the switch. Compilers are able to detect that switch depends on loop invariant and move it out of the loop during compilation.

Comment: @JorgeBellon I just checked with Godbolt and GCC-12 and nope, if I move the loop out of the switch-case, the compiler no longer vectorizes. I guess the compiler does not rerun its vectorizer after reordering the loop. Not the first time I've seen stuff like this happen.

Comment: I just replaced the vectors with an array and almost met my execution speed target. Thanks for the detailed answer, I will use those other suggestions in later versions after I've practiced them enough. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Homer512 you are right: GCC does not, thanks for checking this out. I've checked with Clang++ and it does the right thing so it is not something we should rely on unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

I am nearly 98% sure that the if-else ladder is not the problem.

The `std::vector`s (or whatever container you use) `push_back` function with tons of reallocations and data copying is for me the main candidate for optimization.

Please use the `reserve` function to allocate the needed memory beforehand.

Then move out all invariant stuff, like

```
default_random_engine generator(time(0));
normal_distribution<float> dist(0,1);
```

But without more example code, it is hard to judge.

A profiler will give you better results. Timer functions will not help a lot here.

Comment: Can you suggest some good profilers? I'll also try using an array instead of a `std::vector`. Also about the noise engine, I don't want to invoke it if the `RPL_OPTION` isn't `3` and it stays constant throughout the total execution.

Comment: Just using a standard defined array instead of vectors with push_back() helped me almost reach my target. I'll try other optimizations suggested by @Homer512 and will be accepting their answer as it was more detailed. Thanks a lot though, yours was simpler and easily made that part 3x faster; I would accept both answers if I could.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a piece of code that demands execution speed over anything else

That suggests a non-obvious approach. The code pattern looks familiar enough from a signal processing viewpoint, so `WINDOW_SIZE` is likely non-trivial. In that case, using AVX2 with packed comparisons makes sense.

In short, you pack a whole AVX2 register full of inputs, use two AVX2 registers to store copies of the lower and upper threshold, and issue the two comparisons. This gives you two outputs, where each value is either 0 or `~0`.

Hence, your flag count be determined by or-ing the two registers. It's tempting to count the flags already, but this is considered a slow "horizontal add". Better to keep track of this in another AVX register, and do one horizontal add at the end.

The updates to `filtered_output` depend on the case, but for 1 and 2 you can use AVX for this as well. Choosing between two values based on the bits in a third register can be done with `mm256_blendv_epi8`. You can safely ignore the `8` there, that's the minimum resolution (one byte). If you're doing 32 bits comparisons, your result register will also contain 32 bits outcomes, so `mm256_blendv_epi8` will work with 4*8 bits resolution.

If you have `case 0:` of course should just be a straight copy to `filtered_output`, outside the `if` statements.

Comment: You're assuming the OP works on a platform that supports vector extensions - That might not necessarily be the case.

Comment: How do I learn about AVX2 registers? Yes I am working on signal processing, and `WINDOW_SIZE` ranges from 1024 to 16384, even higher sometimes.
@tofro the platform I'm working on is **Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v3 @ 3.20GHz**

Comment: @Psynapse_261: So in short AVX2 is a commonly available set of vector instructions, including your Xeon. It has its own registers and [its own instructions](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html). You can mostly ignore the register part when using it from C++, the compiler can do register assignment.

Comment: @MSalters ohkay thanks, I'll look into them

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to notice is that you `push_back` on vectors. The code shows no call to `reserve` so this will resize the vector as it grows over and over. That's probably more expensive than anything else in the loop.

The next things concerns the "if-else-ladder":

Have you actually profiled if the ladder is a problem at all? Branches are only expensive when they mispredict. Maybe the branch predictor works juse fine on your input? Assuming this switch statement is executed many times one way to help it out would be to sort the input. Then the if-else-ladder wouldn't jump randomly every time but repeat the same way many times before switching to a new case. But that only helps if the loop runs many times or the cost of sorting will negate any improvement.

And if the switch is repeated many times you can split the input into 3 groups once, for the 3 options in the ladder, and process each group without any if-else-ladder.

Looking closer at the code I see the first 2 cases in the if-else-ladder are identical (except case 2). So you can combine the tests making this a simple "if-else":

```
if ((ans[k] >= upper_th) || (ans[k] < lower_th))
```

Now due to lazy evaluation this will produce the same code as before. But you can do better:

```
if ((ans[k] >= upper_th) | (ans[k] < lower_th))
```

Now both parts get evaluated since there is no lazy evaluation of |. Except compilers are artifical stupids and might just do lazy evaluation anyway. At this point you are fighting the optimizer. Some compilers will optimize this into 2 branches, some leave it at one.

You can use something like the following trick there:

```
static auto fn[] = {
    [&]() { code for first choice; };
    [&]() { code for second choice; };
};
fn[((ans[k] >= upper_th) | (ans[k] < lower_th))]();
```

By turning the condition of your `if` into computing the index of an array the compiler optimization producing 2 branches is circumvented. Hopefully. At least till the next compiler update. :)

When fighting the optimizer you have to recheck your solution every time you update the compiler.

And for case 2 the difference in the code is only what value to push_back. That can be turned into a conditional move on most architectures instead of a branch if you use

```
(ans[k] >= upper_th) ? upper_th : lower_th;
```

for the push_back.

Comment: Replacing the `if` by a computed branch? The branch predictor works best with `if` statements. This looks like a pessimization.

Comment: @MSalters You are thinking this turns into computing the address and jumping to it. But the optimizer should turn that back into an if. All the boilerplate is just to make it not turn the `|` into lazy evaluation with 2 branches. You need something complex enough to disable one bad optimization but not so complex the boilerplate doesn't evaporate. It's a balancing act.

Comment: Alternatively you can insert some inline asm there to disrupt the optimizer from doing the wrong thing. It's crucial though to look at the compiler output first if you need to do anything at all. And if you do something look that it actually does what you wanted. And always measure that the resulting effect actually is faster.

Comment: I will look into the `push_back()` and maybe use an array instead of a vector, but apart from that the `|` statement idea won't work as sometimes I am replacing both cases with different values.

Comment: @Psynapse_261 Only in case 2 and it makes more sense to compute the value with `?` than having a full code block that's 90% identical. Generally pull as much common code out of the if-else-ladder as you can. At a certain size the compiler might surprise you and eliminate the branches for you and replace them with conditional moves.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, sorting **ans** could be a good idea because of bench prediction. But it is up to mostly size of the **ans** . Secondly, if you are using c++20 you can take a look at [LIKELY] and [UNLIKELY] keywords. If you can select which statement is picking mostly or the opposite you can easily use them.

Comment: Sorting `ans` seems like it would affect the output - that's generally unwanted. Also, `[[likely]]` is spelled with two `[[` because it's an _attribute_, not a _keyword_.

Comment: I can't sort `ans`, the filtering is dependent on the order. I am also using c++11